# Authenticate users based on a username / password of windows

Tags: java, spring, jaas

I am new to authentication and autherization, I have to authenticate user from my windows UserId and Password in my web Application using spring. Is it possible in java1.6 and spring2.5. Please provide me some useful links or sample

Comment: Or... you could do some research, then come and ask a specific question should you have one. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for how to ask questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I suppose you want to use spring security + NTLM, check this: http://blog.mediasoft.be/ntlm-with-spring-security-20/ Fairly easy to find using your favorite seasrch engine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Spring but I am familiar with LDAP and Java. A quick google search lead me to [this](http://www.springsource.org/ldap). You can use this to connect to your LDAP server(windows authentication).

Comment: i want to access user maintain in windows active directory through spring.

Comment: Well I guess spring-LDAP will be useful to you. Try reading on that, it basically makes it easier to perform LDAP operations in your spring application. LDAP operations include querying users in windows active directory. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html) offers a ready-made provider for Active Directory authentication, [ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.html). That might be something to look at for you. If you don't want to use spring-security, you always have the option of falling back to using [spring-ldap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/) and doing all the bind/lookup logic yourself. Read the section about [authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/user-authentication.html).